# htaccess mod_rewrite is not working on 1&1

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have a .htaccess file located in my webservers /marssolover/protected folder which allows me to get a file from the protected folder and stream it via the filestreamer.php file located in  the same folder.  mod_rewrite works fine on localhost but not at 1&1.

I have googled  and tried some of the suggestions ending up with this .htaccess file:

```
AddHandler x-mapp-php6 .php

RewriteEngine On
Options -MultiViews
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteBase /MARS/MARSSecure
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ filestreamer.php?file=$1 [L]

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

But, it is still not working.  I've read that it might have something to do with MultiViews, but I thought that was disabled by `Options -MultiViews`

Comment: Have you checked with 1&1 that mod_rewrite is enabled on your hosting?

Comment: @atallon they do support it their response was "Please be informed that our hosting package support that application."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this instead:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !filestreamer\.php              [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/MARS/MARSSecure/(.*)/?        [NC]
RewriteRule .*   /MARS/MARSSecure/filestreamer.php?file=%1 [L,NC]
```

Maps silently

`http://example.com/MARS/MARSSecure/anything`

To:

`http://example.com/MARS/MARSSecure/filestreamer.php?file=anything`

Try using flags [R,L,NC] during testing so you can see the substitution URL.